# error NULL when get value in array with document.querySelector in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
object = ["a","input","textarea","select","img","#content",".view"];
for (var i = 0; i < oj.length; i++) {
    var resources = document.querySelector(object[i]);
    resources.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){alert("test");}, false);
}
```

Error `TypeError: resources is null` , how to fix it ?

Comment: Also, object is speacial type name, don't use it.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the basic check for non-falsy value (element *matched* the selector) is the way to go:

```
if (resources) {
    resources.addEventListener("mouseover", function() { ... }, false);
}
```

Comment: +1 For being first and correct, I think checking for null directly and not for a non-falsy value is probably more concise

Answer (score 1):

There are no elements matching one of the selectors in your array.  Do a simple check to make sure its not undefined, before attaching the event.

```
var object = ["a","input","textarea","select","img","#content",".view"];
for (var i = 0; i < oj.length; i++) {
    var resources = document.querySelector(object[i]);
    if(resources){
    resources.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){alert("test");}, false);
    }
}
```